# Помогите решить задачу по теории вероятности

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Заходят как-то 322 математика в бар, нумеруются от 1 до 322, каждый выбирает наугад кого-то кроме себя и записывает его номер на бумажку. Бармен вызывает первого математика, он заказывает пиво тому кто написан у него на листке, после чего к бармену подходит следующий по очереди математик кому еще не заказали пиво, заказывает тому кто написан у него на листке и так далее.

Сколько математиков останется без пива в матожидании?

Напишите ответ десятичной дробью, округленной до шестого знака после запятой.

Мое решение:
Я расписала первых трех математиков.

Первый математик не выбирает 320/321 математиков с вероятностью 322/322 не выбрать того, у кого уже есть пиво.

Второй математик не выбирает 320/321 математиков с вероятностью 321/322 не выбрать того, у кого уже есть пиво.

Третий математик не выбирает 320/321 математиков с вероятностью 320/322 не выбрать того, у кого уже есть пиво.

Считаю сумму ряда от n = 0 до n = 321

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается 160.996884 или 160.996885 и это неправильные ответы.

Или если взять тот же ряд от 1 до 322, то получается ровно 160, что тоже неправильно.

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в логике решения.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала решить задачу для 3-х математиков. Потом подумайте, как формулу составить.

Comment: `322*((322-2)/(322-1))^(322-1)=118`? Здесь `(322-2)/(322-1)` - вероятность того, что `k`-й математик выбрал не `i`-го.

Comment: У меня вычислительным экспериментом :) получилось, что ровно половина...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, ваш ответ подошел, было бы интересно узнать решение :)

Comment: У меня тоже при моделировании на питоне получилось в районе 0.5 +/- 0.00005 )

Comment: В моём ответе ошибка: я упустил вот это: "следующий по очереди математик **кому еще не заказали пиво**".

Comment: За решением к @CrazyElf — он на него намекал. То, что я писал в удаленном комментарии (если кто успел прочесть), то это было следствие неверно понятого условия задачи...

Comment: @Harry Мне лениво думать над формулой, просто мне показалось, что если решить задачу для небольшого `n` сначала, то должно стать понятно куда двигаться )

Comment: @maestro Ага, без этого условия получается не половина, а где-то `0.366`, ну то есть в районе 118, да

Comment: В дополненной вами логике изъян, как мне представляется, в том, что события не являются независимыми.

Comment: Изъян уже на втором математике. Если он получил пиво от первого, то он совсем не участвует в дальнейших расчетах.

Answer (score 3):

В каждый момент есть математики трех сортов: пившие пиво (П); уже поставившие пиво другому, но еще не пившие сами (Н); и еще способные поставить пиво (С). Очевидно, что постановка пива для Н увеличивает П на 1, и уменьшает С на 1. Постановка пива для П увеличивает на 1 Н и уменьшает С на 1. Постановка пива для С увеличивает на 1 и П, и Н, и уменьшает С на 2. Нарисуем траекторию: точки с координатами (П,Н) от начала и до конца обслуживания. Она начинается с (0,0) и идет к точке, где П+Н=322 (а С = 0).

Но для каждой траектории найдется зеркальная ей, в которой просто П и Н поменяны местами. Так что задача симметрична, и в среднем в конце и П, и Н равны по 161.

Решение нашлось [тут](https://ru-math.livejournal.com/511593.html).

Comment: Опишите процедуру зеркальной симметрии.

Comment: Одной ПН-траектории соответствует несколько конфигураций. Докажите что зеркальному отражению будет соответствовать тоже число комбинаций.

Comment: "*Одной ПН-траектории соответствует несколько конфигураций*" — это как? Скорее уж одной конечной конфигурации может соответствовать несколько траекторий.

Comment: ПН-траектория: `0,0-1,1-1,1-2,1-3,1`. Ей соответствуют три конфигурации: `2113 2313 2413`. Симметричная ПН-траектория: `0,0-1,1-1,1-1,2-1,3`. Конфигурации: `2122 2322 2422`. Нужно предъявить отображение из первой тройки во вторую. Я пока не вижу простого способа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Наверное, я тупой сегодня, но что такое конфигурация? И как вы из 1,1 попали в 1,1 же в первом примере?

Comment: Конфигурация `2113` -> первый поит второго, второй - первого, третий - первого, четвёртый - третьего. В траектории сохраняется место если очередной человек (в примерах - второй) уже с пивом, бармен его пропускает. Я его в траектории сохраняю.

Comment: А зачем переводить конфигурации из одной в другую? Мне кажется, что куда важнее, что задача симметрична относительно П и Н, так что можно даже не рассматривать, какая именно конфигурация(и) приводит к той или иной траектории, нет? Хотя, возможно, я рассуждаю как физик, для которого "из соображений симметрии" звучит вполне доказательно :) Как вариант: пусть есть П и Н, тогда с вероятностью П/N произойдет увеличение Н, с H/N - увеличение П, и (N-П-Н)/N - и того, и второго. При замене П<->Н уравнения не меняются, так что конечные вероятности не меняются. Где тут проблема? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: В ваших рассуждениях нет проблемы. Она немного дальше. Пусть к паре (A, B) приводит 10^9 комбинаций, а к паре (B, A) только 10^3. При расчёте математического ожидания получится (10^9 * A + 10^3 * B) / (10^9 + 10^3). Но это не равно (A + B) / 2 как нужно для решения задачи.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy К паре B,A не может приводить иное количество путей, чем к паре A,B. Просто из симметрии. Просто поменяем местами левую и правую части — что изменится? Точно те же пути...

Comment: "поменяем местами левую и правую части" - не понятно. Вы предлагаете перевернуть очередь математиков задом наперед? Я так и не увидел симметрию. :(

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что изменится, если вместо постановки пива для Н будет постановка пива для П, и наоборот? Что изменится?

Comment: П уже с пивом. Я туплю, видимо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Конфигурация 3341, например - кому поставит пиво второй математик?...

Comment: Снова третьему.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy То есть уже пившему (П). Отвлечемся от пива. Есть состояния А, В и С. И переходы. С вероятностью, пропорциональной А, на 1 увеличивается количество В. С вероятностью, пропорциональной В, на 1 увеличивается количество А. И с оставшейся до1 вероятностью увеличиваются и А, и В. И так, пока С не станет нулем. Так симметричность очевиднее? В задаче "есть состояния D и Е" и далее по тексту — чему будет равна конечная вероятность D — вероятности А или вероятности В?

Comment: Стало чуточку яснее. Думаю что смогу по индукции доказать что число маршрутов в `(Н, П, C)` и в `(П, Н, С)` одинаково. Спасибо!